# How to find out WSL2 version?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

At the moment the latest WSL2 version is [0.58.3](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/0.58.3). I just run `wsl.exe --update` and now I would like to know which version of WSL2 I'm running. I've tried both `--version` and `--status` flags without success:

```
PS C:\Users> wsl.exe --status
Default Distribution: Ubuntu
Default Version: 2

Windows Subsystem for Linux was last updated on 6.5.2022
The Windows Subsystem for Linux kernel can be manually updated with 'wsl --update',
but automatic updates cannot occur due to your system settings.
To receive automatic kernel updates, please enable the Windows Update setting:
'Receive updates for other Microsoft products when you update Windows'.
For more information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel.

Kernel version: 5.10.102.1

PS C:\Users> wsl.exe --version
Invalid command line option: --version
```

How can I check my current WSL2 version? Please note that I know I can use `wsl.exe --list --verbose` to see if I'm using WSL 1 or 2.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few ways to determine the installed WSL version, depending on how it was installed.  Given that your installation does not have the `--version` command available, it's most likely you are running an *in-box* version of WSL (one that comes with Windows as a *feature*).

The `--version` option is only available in the *Application* version of WSL (installed from the [Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage) or a [WSL Releases](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases) download).

- Older, *in-box/feature* versions of WSL are installed with Windows releases/updates, and are versioned after their Windows build.

  Older [Preview versions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes) (under Windows 10) also follow this versioning and were released with Insider/Preview builds of Windows.  It's extremely unlikely that you are running a Windows 10 Preview version at this point, since all Developer/Insider builds have currently expired.

  The latest in-box version at this time is 22000, which corresponds to the Windows 11 release.  Even in Windows 11, 22H2, the in-box feature-set is still the same as in 22000.

  For in-box/feature versions (and older in-box Preview versions), you can find the version by either:

  - Using File Explorer to navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe`, right-click, select *Properties*, go to the *Details* tab, and look for the *File Version*.
  - Or, from PowerShell:

    ```
    (get-item C:\windows\system32\wsl.exe).VersionInfo.FileVersion
    ```
- Starting soon after the Windows 11 release, WSL became available in the [Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage) as an *application package*, first as a Preview, and with 1.0.0, as a generally-available release.

  These application packages are numbered with the point-release format you mention above, with the latest version currently being the 1.0.0 release.  You can see a history of these releases in the [WSL Github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases) and even still download and install them if you wish.

  These releases of WSL does add a `wsl --version/-v` command which shows something like:

  ```
  WSL version: 0.58.3.0
  Kernel version: 5.10.102.1
  WSLg version: 1.0.33
  MSRDC version: 1.2.2924
  Direct3D version: 1.601.0
  Windows version: 10.0.22000.613
  ```

  You could also get just the WSL version by checking the Appx package that is installed from the Store through PowerShell:

  ```
  (Get-AppxPackage | ? Name -eq "MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemforLinux").Version
  ```

*Related*:

In the *application package* (Store) version, you can update the full WSL release (including the kernel) with `wsl --update`.

However, in older, in-box versions of WSL, the `wsl --update` command will *only* update the WSL2 kernel to the latest release.  Note that this may or may not correspond to the latest [available on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/releases), as I believe these are usually given a test-run through the Preview before being made generally available.

`wsl --help` shows the following information `--update` on older, in-box versions of WSL:

```
--update [Options]
        If no options are specified, the WSL 2 kernel will be updated
        to the latest version.

        Options:
            --rollback
                Revert to the previous version of the WSL 2 kernel.
```

Comment: Excellent answer! FYI the WSL change log for released versions is available from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes

Answer (score 3):

You can type in your Windows terminal

`wsl cat /proc/version`

The output will look something like this:

```
wsl cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (oe-user@oe-host) (x86_64-msft-linux-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.34.0.20200220) #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023
```